# User populated box will not change if input changes

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

The drop down is populated from a database "meal_planner I am trying to get the drop down to populate the rest of the row based on the users selection. Currently, only the first selection works; if anything else is selected, it still uses the first choice. I just kind of pieced this together.

```
<?php
$link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysqli_select_db($link,"meal_planner");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else { 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="form1" action="" method="post">
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <?php
  $res=mysqli_query($link,"select name from protein");
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
  {
  ?>
  <option><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>

  <?php
  }

  ?>

  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

getuser.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

th {text-align: left;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','meal_planner');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
$sql="SELECT * FROM protein WHERE protein_id = '".$q."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['calories'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['protein'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['carbs'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['fats'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getuser.php` shouldn't return a whole web page. It should just return the snippet that goes into the `<div id="txtHint">`

Comment: Your `<option>` elements don't have `value` attributes. So the values will be `protein_name`, not `protein_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't put the `protein_id` into the `<option>` elements.

```
$res=mysqli_query($link,"select name, protein_id from protein");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row["protein_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
```

When there's no `value` attribute, it uses the text of the element, so you're ending the protein name as the select value. Then when you use `intval($q)`, it returns `0` because the protein name is not a valid integer, and the query in the AJAX call always gets the protein with `protein_id = 0`.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it!!